# Visual Studio Lightswitch - change Password Rules

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

im wondering if it is possible to change the password credentials required when using a visual studio light switch application.

by this I mean when adding a password to a user, a number, upper case letter and symbol are required, is it possible to say remove the symbol?

thanks for any tips or links to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution.. in your web.config file find the code between the provider tags. the code below lets the user put in any combination of characters/symbols/numbers providing they make a total of 5 or more

```
>   <providers>
>     <clear />
>     <add name="AspNetMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
> connectionStringName="_IntrinsicData"
> applicationName="TimLeungsApplication" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
> requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
> minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="5"
> />   </providers>
```